# Check LINQ query against SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

Is there any way to in .NET to see what LINQ query against database we are firing? For eg. I am wring a query in LINQ and I want to see that what SQL query is firing to communicate with database.

Is there any Visual Studio window or any other way?

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: SQL Profiler, if you are using MSSQL. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJ8Dyv4Uk6E

Comment: I am using SQL RDBMS

Comment: SQL RDBMS? Is this Microsoft, Oracle, MySQL, Postgre or...?

Comment: MSSQL, this is Microsoft

Comment: is there not any way in Visual Studio?

Comment: If you use EF6 this article is helpful http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/08/ef6-sql-logging-part-1-simple-logging/

Comment: you may be looking for https://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: You can use `IntelliTrace` window available in Ultimate versions of VS

Comment: IntelliTrace  is not to check LINQ against SQL query

Answer (score 11):

Are you looking for something like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx)

```
var context = new MyContext();
context.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

Then whenever a query is executed, you'll see an output like :

```
var customers = context.Customers.ToList();
```

> Opened connection at 30-3-2015 13:48:03 +02:00
>
> SELECT 
>       [Extent1].[Guid] AS [Guid],
>       [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName],
>       [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName],
>       [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email],
>       [Extent1].[Created] AS [Created]
>       FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
>
> -- Executing at 30-3-2015 13:48:03 +02:00
>
> -- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader
>
> Closed connection at 30-3-2015 13:48:03 +02:00

Comment: And this works regardless what type of database is used.

Comment: Where I have to write this line, in particular class or in every class where want to check?

Comment: @Parveen You'll need to attach it to every context you instantiate. All the queries executed by that context will be logged. I added the context declaration line to the answer. Hope this helps

Comment: and where need to check the output in Console or Output Window?

Comment: @Parveen yes, the result is written into the _Output_ window, from the "Show output from" list, select _Debug_.

Comment: Thank you very much and also to all guise for their healthy participant. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a DbContext on which you firing your LINQ queries you can simply set the `DbContext.Database.Log` property to something like this:

```
yourContext.Database.Log = (msg => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(msg, "SQL"));
```

After this, every SQL query shows up in the Debug console from your Visual Studio with the category SQL.

Comment: And this works regardless what type of database is used.

Answer (score 4):

You can use SQL Profiler to see how the LINQ expression is translated into SQL statement.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use SQL Server Profiler, Trace or Extended Events. First two are deprecated.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630354(v=sql.105).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The question was `or any other way`. So this answer is quite legitimate. Hello downvoter...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log(v=vs.110).aspx) property of DataContext object. Also, it depends on the type of application you are using.

For Web Application:-

```
db.Log = Response.Output;
```

For Console Application:-

```
db.Log = Console.Out;
```

Apart from this you can also use the [GetCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `DataContext` class. `Sql Server Profiler` is again an obvious option.